# Unity Animation (2D) - Cannot drag sprite into animation

Tags: unity, 2d, animation

I am trying to create animations for my sprite which are configured to the "Multiple" option. When I try to drag the sprite into the timeline for the animation it won't do anything. It will just go back into the folder like nothing happened. I don't know if this is normal or there is a problem.

Thank You.

*EDIT* - First I created a 2D animation, I gave it a name, docked and locked the animation then tried to drag the sprite into the timeline and didn't let add components nor drag the sprite i spliced.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this problem. Creating an Animator and animation clip from a SpriteRenderer and dragging a new sprite into the animation timeline creates a sprite animation property on my object as expected. Can you edit your question to walk us through every step needed to reproduce your problem in a new, empty project? Make sure you explain or screenshot every detail so we can spot any missing step.

Comment: When I say "every step" I mean that very literally. Tell us every single button you pressed. I notice you don't mention anything about selecting an object that has a sprite renderer on it, but because you've been so brief here I can't tell whether that's included in one of your listed steps or not. So, to ensure there's no ambiguity, tell us *everything*. We don't charge by the character here, so don't be afraid to post a full page of instructions.

Comment: I often do something similar. If I remember correctly it was related to next: It is not posible to edit animations with the animator/animation assets selected. It must be the animator assigned to a component/game object and that game object selected.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; Create animations by creating a game object with an animator use the animation window to create a new clip.

I believe this to be a bug* in Unity.
I have had this issue multiple times before, and have quit working early in frustration with it on multiple occasions.

If you create an animation (Animation Clip) through the project browser context menu you cannot drag and drop sprites into it.
However; if you create the animation through an animation on a game object you are able to drag sprites into it.

*Animation clips created through the context menu have different inspector properties than ones created through the animation ui as well. Though from what I can they have identical content/metadata except that the ones created through the animation UI have loop time defaulted to 1.